# laravel and guzzle auth

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, guzzle

Hi i want to consume a service and i use laravel 5.x with guzzle with this code i can send request and i use the correct api-key but i always obtain 403 forbidden....

```
public function searchP(Request $request) {

        $targa = request('targa');

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $url = 'https://xxx.it/api/xxx/xxx-number/'.$targa.'/xxx-xxxx';
        $api_key ='xxxxxcheepohxxxx';

        try {
            $response = $client->request(
                'GET',
                $url,
                ['auth' => [null, $api_key]]);

        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContent());
        }

        // Get JSON
        $result = $response->json();
     }
```

Why? I cannot understand

In postman i write in the AUTHORIZATION label this

- key : x-apikey
- value: xxxxxcheepohxxxx
- Add to header

and it works.
i also tried this

```
  ....  try {
                $response = $client->request('GET',$url,[
                    'headers' => [
                        'x-apikey', $api_key
                       ]
                    ]);
    
            } catch .....
```

but doesn't work
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be this, you have a typo

```php
  ....  try {
                $response = $client->request('GET',$url,[
                    'headers' => [
                        'x-apikey'=> $api_key
                       ]
                    ]);
    
            } catch .....
```

Comment: wow ok it work but it give me 500 internal server error and this message exception: "GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException"
file: "/home2/wlimaser/public_html/check/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php"
line: 111
message: "Client error: `GET https://xxx.it/api/xxx/xxx-number/XXXX/xxx-xxxx` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:↵{"errors":["Coverage not found"]}↵"
trace: [{file: "/home2/wlimaser/public_html/check/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php", line: 66,…},…]

Comment: the reposponse is correct' errors => coverage not found 'so why it gives me error 404 and the html page error 500? in chrome browser is also red

Comment: @MarcoBozzola it might be the api, see "Coverage not found"

Comment: Mmm yes but for example in postman i Just obtain the json errors....not the 404 mmm

Comment: my question is that when i obtein data that is when TARGA exists is 200 and i obtain json of datas, when TARGA doesn't exist i obtein a 404 not found and a guzzle error client response in json response:↵{"errors":["Coverage not found"]}. How can i handle this

Comment: ok i solved i had to insert in request this ['http_errors' => false]